# Animated scroll to id to different page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a menu that had menu items with the link like this `/about/#our_vision`. I need to scroll to following section of page with simple animation.I had tried many ways and tried with this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('li#menu-item-65 > ul.sub-menu > li > a').bind('click.smoothscroll', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 95
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

My menu has position fixed style and because of this anyway without and animation link on click on following section but a bit more because of menu fixed style.How can I fix this?

Comment: You need a jQuery **on that other page** that waits for the *hash* could be read, than if existent, scroll to the desired element ID

Comment: Ok how I can change my code for working properly?

Comment: Can you suggest me a little how to continue?